# Why pytorch model cannot recognize the tensors I defined?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm just learn pytorch recently.
And I try to write a same model like the paper that I have read for practice.

This is the PDF of the paper I refer.
https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3178876.3186066?download=true

Here is the code what I wrote.

```
class Tem(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_size, hidden_size):
        super(Tem, self).__init()
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.leaf_size = 0

        self.xgb_model = None
        self.vec_embedding = None

        self.multi_hot_Q = None
        self.user_embedding = torch.nn.Linear(1, embedding_size)
        self.item_embedding = torch.nn.Linear(1, embedding_size)

    def pretrain(self, ui_attributes, labels):
        print("Start XGBoost Training...")
        self.xgb_model = XGBoost(ui_attributes, labels)
        self.leaf_size = self.xgb_model.leaf_size
        self.vec_embedding = Variable(torch.rand(self.embedding_size, self.leaf_size, requires_grad=True))
        
        self.h = Variable(torch.rand(self.hidden_size, 1, requires_grad=True))
        self.att_w = Variable(torch.rand(2 * self.embedding_size, self.hidden_size, requires_grad=True))
        self.att_b = Variable(torch.rand(self.leaf_size, self.hidden_size, requires_grad=True))

        self.r_1 = Variable(torch.rand(self.embedding_size, 1, requires_grad=True))
        self.r_2 = Variable(torch.rand(self.embedding_size, 1, requires_grad=True))
        self.bias = Variable(torch.rand(1, 1, requires_grad=True))

    def forward(self, ui_ids, ui_attributes):
        if self.xgb_model == None:
            raise Exception("Please run Tem.pretrain() to pre-train XGBoost model first.")

        n_data = len(ui_ids)

        att_input = torch.FloatTensor(ui_attributes)
        self.multi_hot_Q = torch.FloatTensor(self.xgb_model.multi_hot(att_input)).permute(0,2,1)

        vq = self.vec_embedding * self.multi_hot_Q

        id_input = torch.FloatTensor(ui_ids)

        user_embedded = self.user_embedding(id_input[:,0].reshape(n_data, 1))

        item_embedded = self.item_embedding(id_input[:,1].reshape(n_data, 1))

        ui = (user_embedded * item_embedded).reshape(n_data, self.embedding_size, 1)

        ui_repeat = ui.repeat(1, 1, self.leaf_size)

        cross = torch.cat([ui_repeat, vq], dim=1).permute(0,2,1)

        re_cross = corss.reshape(cross.shape[0] * cross.shape[1], cross.shape[2])

        attention = torch.mm(re_cross, self.att_w)
        attention = F.leaky_relu(attention + self.att_b.repeat(n_data, 1))
        attention = torch.mm(attention, self.h).reshape(n_data, self.leaf_size)
        attention = F.softmax(attention).reshape(n_data, self.leaf_size, 1)
        attention = self.vec_embedding.permute(1,0) * attention.repeat(1,1,20)

        pool = torch.max(attention, 1).values

        y_hat = self.bias.repeat(n_data, 1) + torch.mm(ui.reshape(n_data, self.embedding_size), self.r_1) + torch.mm(pool, self.r_2)
        y_hat = F.softmax(torch.nn.Linear(1, 2)(y_hat))
        return y_hat
```

My question is...It seems torch didn't know what tensor should be calculate gradient in backward propagation.

```
print(tem)
```

```
Tem(
(user_embedding): Linear(in_features=1, out_features=20, bias=True)
(item_embedding): Linear(in_features=1, out_features=20, bias=True)
)
```

I googled this problem, someone says those tensors should use `torch.autograd.Variable()`, but it didn't solve my problem. And someone says autograd directly supports tensors now. `torch.autograd.Variable()` is not necessary.

```
loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.Adagrad(tem.parameters(), lr=0.02)
for t in range(20):
    prediction = tem(ids_train, att_train)

    loss = loss_func(prediction, y_train)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if t % 5 == 0:
        print("loss: ", loss)
```

```
loss: tensor(0.8133, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
loss: tensor(0.8133, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
loss: tensor(0.8133, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
loss: tensor(0.8133, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not related to `Variable`. As you said, it's not necessary anymore. To compute the gradients of a tensor declared in a model (that extends `nn.Module`) you need to include them into the model's parameters using the method `nn.Parameter()`. For example, to include `self.h`, you can do:

```
self.h = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(10,10)
```

Now, when you call `loss.backward()` it'll collect the gradient for this variable (of course, `loss` must be dependent on `self.h`).